# Licences of 3 party code: What do I have to keep in mind? What's the best way to organize them?

Tags: python, licensing, virtualenv

I'd like to provide a Python application to a client as zipped Virtualenv directory. I'm wondering what's the best way to include the licenses of Python itself and of the used 3 party libraries.

What do I have to keep in mind?

I'd need to include the licences of Python, pip and any installed libraries, right?

What would be the best way to organize the licences? At the moment I'd include every licence in a file named Licence.txt. Would this be enough, or would I need to specify the exact path where the used code can be found?

This is my first project for a client and I'm kind of clueless ;)

I've tried to find the answer somewhere on the internet but I didn't find anything.

Thanks!

Best regards,

Daniel

Comment: While it doesn't change much about the question, why distribute a zipped virtualenv? Virtualenvs have their path hardcoded (there's a flag for making it "relocatable", but it's experimental and currently does not work at all on Windows), even if it can be relocated it will be tied to numerous other assumptions about the system, and let's not even touch on different operating systems (or just different versions of C libraries), etc. -- in short, that's no proper distribution procedure.

Comment: Migrating this to programmers.stackexchange.com might be good, i guess...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading the [PythonSoftwareFoundationFAQ](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSoftwareFoundationLicenseFaq#If_I_bundle_Python_with_my_application.2C_what_do_I_need_to_include_in_my_software_and.2BAC8-or_printed_documentation.3F). This is probably what you are looking for:

> You must retain all copyright notices found in the code you are redistributing and include a copy of the PSF License and all of the other licenses in the Python "license stack" with the software distribution. The "license stack" is a result of the history of Python's development as described here (this page also lists all licenses in the stack).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a lawyer, but just on common sense I'm pretty sure that when you're distributing a big collection of copyrighted documents covered by numerous licenses that you would have to clearly communicate what licenses cover what documents in order for the licensees to know what license conditions they have to adhere to.

i.e. It seems ridiculous to suppose you could distribute a big blob of code and say "some of this is covered by the GPL, some is public domain, and some is covered by a proprietary license" without saying which is which. If you did, someone could then use some of your proprietary code as if it were public domain, and make the argument that they believed in good faith that it was public domain based on your information.